# How to update related attributes while saving objects in Rails Active Record

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, design-patterns, activerecord

My current logic is, taking two inputs from form where one is primary book and one is secondary book and save it to database with is_primary check being true for primary book and false for secondary. We can have multiple secondary books.

I have a table books:
Table name: books

- book_id
- book_name

And I have another table authors:
Table name: authors

- author_id
- author_name

And I have relation table as below:
Table name: author_book

- author_book_id
- book_id
- author_id
- is_primary (Bool)

Code for form:

```
  <div class="elem-set">
    <div class="elem-label">
      <label>Author</label>
    </div>

    <%= f.select :associated_author,
    Author.sort_by_name.map{|t| ["#{t.id}: #{t.name}", t.name]},
    { include_blank: "No Author" },
    { class: 'chzn-select', multiple: false }
    %><br /><br />
  </div>


  <div class="elem-set">
    <div class="elem-label">
      <label>Primary Book</label>
    </div>

    <%= f.select :associated_primary_book,
    Book.sort_by_name.map{|n| ["#{n.book_name}: #{n.book_id}", n.book_name]},
    { include_blank: "No Book" },
    { class: 'chzn-select', multiple: false }
    %><br /><br />
  </div>


  <div class="elem-set">
    <div class="elem-label">
      <label>Secondary Book</label>
    </div>

    <%= f.select :associated_secondary_book,
    Book.sort_by_name.map{|n| ["#{n.book_name}: #{n.book_id}", n.book_name]},
    { include_blank: "No Book" },
    { class: 'chzn-select', multiple: true }
    %><br /><br />
  </div>
```

**MODEL**
Book class:

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :author_book, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :authors, through: :author_book

    scope :sort_by_name, -> { select([:book_id, :book_name]).order('book_name ASC') }
end
```

Authors class:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :author_book, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, through: :author_book
  def associated_primary_books=(fetched_books)
    self.books.clear
    if !fetched_books.empty?
        self.books << Book.find_by_name(fetched_books)
        #is_primary=> true
    end
  end


  def associated_secondary_books=(fetched_books)
    fetched_books = fetched_books.delete_if { |x| x.empty? }
    if !fetched_books.empty?
      fetched_books.each do |book|
        self.books << Book.find_by_name(book)
      end
    end
  end
  
end
```

AuthorBook class:

```
class AuthorBook < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :authors
  belongs_to :books
  
end
```

**Controller**
Author controller

```
AuthorController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @Author = Author.new(params[:author])

    respond_to do |format|
      begin
        retries ||= 0
        if @author.save
          flash[:notice] = 'Author created.'
          Event.init(user: current_user.id, type: "Create Author", details: {
            :author => @author.id
          })
          format.html { redirect_to action: 'show',
                :id => @author.id
          }
        end
      rescue ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid => e
        flash[:error] = 'error'
        redirect_to action: 'new'
      end
    end
  end
```

**ISSUE**: What I want to achieve is whenever I save book object, I also somehow save the `is_primary` as true or false which is present in author_book table.

1. When I try to add book to author, it gets saved successfully. But I am unable to update the is_primary attribute resulting in all
   books as secondary. I get undefined method error if I try to update
   the is_primary attribute. How do I access the is_primary attribute
   which is present in relation table and solve this cleanly?
2. If I try to update the author_book table after adding Book, it returns empty array because everything is saved after Author is
   created.
3. This is stub code with example I created and not the complete code.

We are using Rails 3.

Comment: Your table should be named `author_books` and the association `has_many :author_books`. I'm kind of surprised this hasn't caused an error yet.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you want to do here is loop through and upsert the records. Except Rails 3 does not support upserts which was only just added in Rails 6. What you can do is:

```
class Author < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :author_books, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :books, through: :author_books
  
  def associated_primary_books=(fetched_books)
    fetched_books.select(&:present?).each do |id|
      ab = author_books.find_or_initialize_by(book_id: id)
      ab.is_primary = true
      ab.save unless new_record?
    end  
  end

  def associated_secondary_books=(fetched_books)
    fetched_books.select(&:present?).each do |id|
      ab = author_books.find_or_initialize_by(book_id: id)
      ab.is_primary = false
      ab.save unless new_record?
    end 
  end
end
```

Note that I'm using the id of the book instead of the name. Don't pass names around - that's silly since ambiguity is bound to happen as book titles are hardly unique.

Comment: Hello max, I am getting error for find_or_initialize_by since the record for author is inserted in author controller after associated_primary_books is called. From what I observed, associated_primary_books assigns books objects in self.books and this gets saved to database once @Author = Author.new(params[:author]) is called in author controller. Any ideas to help here?

Comment: I was thinking to move this code below Author.new(params[:author]) but that doesn't look nice at all. Error I am getting is:
undefined method `find_or_initialize_by' for []:ActiveRecord::Relation